# Setting a String in JSF and Seam using selectOneMenu populated by JS

Tags: jsf, seam

I have a string that is being set from selectonemenu.  The values in the menu depend on the selection in another menu, and are populated using JavaScript. Everything behaves fine on the front end (the menus update appropriately, etc), but when we submit the changes, the string is not being set.  The menu has a converter, and getAsObject is being called.  Does anybody know why the string isn't being set?

Edit.jspx

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{detectorInstance.type}" converter="detectorConverter" onchange="updateSubTypes(this, '#{applicationName}')">
    <s:selectItems value="#{detectors.detectors}" var="detectorSelection" label="#{detectorSelection.name}" noSelectionLabel="Unknown"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>    
<a4j:outputPanel id="detectorSubType">
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{detectorInstance.detectorSubType}" converter="detectorSubTypeConverter"/>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

DetectorSubTypeConverter.java

```
@Name("detectorSubTypeConverter")
@BypassInterceptors
@org.jboss.seam.annotations.faces.Converter
public class DetectorSubTypeConverter implements Converter {
    public Object getAsObject(final FacesContext facesContext, final UIComponent uiComponent, final String identifier) {
        return identifier;
    }

    public String getAsString(final FacesContext facesContext, final UIComponent uiComponent, final Object o) {
        return o.toString();
    }
}
```

detectors.js

```
function updateSubTypes(typeSelect, appName) {
    var jsonRoot = appName + "/services/rest/detectors/detectors";

    jQuery.getJSON(jsonRoot, function(data) {
        var subTypes = getSubTypes(typeSelect, data);
        var subTypeSelect = typeSelect.next().firstChild;
        subTypeSelect.options.length = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < subTypes.length; i++) {
            subTypeSelect.options[i] = new Option(subTypes[i], subTypes[i], false, false);
        }
    });
}

function getSubTypes(typeSelect, detectors) {
    var selection = typeSelect.options[typeSelect.selectedIndex].text;
    var subtypes = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < detectors.length; i++) {
        var uuid = detectors[i]['detector']['name'];
        if (selection == uuid) {
            for (var j = 0; j < detectors[i]['detector']['subtypes'].length; j++) {
                subtypes[j] = detectors[i]['detector']['subtypes'][j]['name'];
            }
        }
    }

    return subtypes;
}
```

Comment: in your 2nd selectOneMenu I see a value but no list - is that intentional?  How are you submitting the changes?

Comment: Yes - the empty list is intentional.  The js call populates it based on the selection in the type list.  I"m pretty new to jsf/seam so I'm not really sure what all is required to submit changes.  I thought that was handled with the "Value" attribute.

Comment: Does a selectOneMenu require a selectItems?  And if so, does it have to include the value to be submitted?

Comment: If you are not selecting from a list, why use a select one menu?  It looks like you're just populating a field.  You're not giving the user a choice.  Why not just have your first selectOneMenu populate an outputText and the backing bean?  Or is "#{detectorInstance.detectorSubType}" supposed to be the list?

Comment: The second list is there because there are a limited number of values that the user can have, however, the contents of the list change depending on the selection in the previous list.  We don't want to use an outputText because there are only so many valid options. So, if the user selects "type 1" in the type selectOneMenu, the valid subtypes are A, B, D, G, and Y.  But if the user selects "type 2" in the type selectOneMenu, the valid subtypes are C, E, L, M, N, Q, and S.

Comment: I understand but that's not what you have here.   value="#{detectorInstance.detectorSubType}" is not a list of items it is what the user has SELECTED from the list of items.  You want 2 lists, so a selection from list 1 populates s:selectItems in list 2.  A selectOneMenu without something to select from (s:selectItems) isn't a selection list.  This will only show an empty field with no values populated.

Comment: I've never tried to populate a selectOneMenu with js but some googling got me this http://www.coderanch.com/t/506612/JSF/java/submit-form-populate-selectOneMenu-javascript

Comment: Ah - thank you.  That explains a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think populating items for selectOneMenu by JS is the right way to work with Seam/JSF. The reason is that when you show a dropdown with a list of items, Seam/JSF will check if the submitted value is in the list for security reason.

The right way would be:

- Handle onchange event of the first dropdown and recalculate the items for the second dropdown on server
- Then rerender the second dropdown

The idea is as follows:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{detectorInstance.type}" converter="detectorConverter" onchange="updateSubTypes(this, '#{applicationName}')">
    <s:selectItems value="#{detectors.detectors}" var="detectorSelection" label="#{detectorSelection.name}" noSelectionLabel="Unknown"/>
    <a4j:ajax event="click" execute="@this" render="detectorSubType" 
        listener="#{detectorInstance.onTypeChange}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
<a4j:outputPanel id="detectorSubType">
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{detectorInstance.detectorSubType}" converter="detectorSubTypeConverter">
        <f:selectItem value="#{detectorInstance.types}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

The items for second dropdown is from `detectorInstance.types`. In `detectorInstance.onTypeChange`, you recalculate `detectorInstance.types` and then rerender it by `render="detectorSubType"`

Comment: I think this is correct, but we were actually trying to move away from this method to avoid the ajax call.